# Traditional Logic: About Judgment

Tags: logic

I am reading "Introduction to Traditional Logic" by Scott M. Sullivan. In the section about Judgment there is a sentence I am not able to grasp:

> ... judgment refer our concepts back to the source from which they came.

I can not really understand this quite well. Could anyone explain what it really means?

Comment: He's stating that judgements deal with abstract mental concepts as well as the physical thing they're about. In his apple example, he is saying that judgements connect our mental concept of "apple" with the specific, physical apple that we're currently eating. He defines what he means by concept in the section above the section on judgements.

Comment: I haven't read this book so I can't comment directly; but according to Kant, judgement is the highest human faculty in that it allows us to seek out what is significant from the insignificant, the truthful from the false, and the probable from the improbable; all this is neccessary substrate to logic; formal logic which moves from valid to valid via rules of inference isn't enough. A fuller understanding of logic needs to link it organically with the other faculties of human reasoning. Quite often, this is hardly touched upon in modern books of logic - which is a pity.

Comment: See [Judgement](https://maartens.home.xs4all.nl/philosophy/Dictionary/J/Judgement.htm) : "Decision that something - usually an idea or statement - is true or false, or probable or improbable, or good or bad." Thus, it is the (mental) act of assessing the truth value of a sentence or the corerspondence to reality of a concept (or mental representation).

Comment: @Not_Here Thanks for clarifying it, it is now much clear to me.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA A very good definition judgment, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

The term [judgment](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-judgment/) has a long history in philosophy.

We can see Arnauld & Nicole's [Port-Royal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/port-royal-logic/) :

> [ [page 23](https://books.google.it/books?id=2dBA9kEx47MC&pg=PA23) ] *Judging* is the action in which the mind, bringing together different ideas, affirms
>   of one that it is the other, or denies of one that it is the other. This occurs when, for example, having the idea of the earth and the idea of round, I affirm or deny of the earth that it is round.
>
> The action of the mind in which it forms a judgment from several others is called *reasoning*.